# Skip Uploads Folder in gitlab Pipelines

Tags: git, gitlab, cpanel

I configure `.yml` file in gitlab for auto deploy in cPanel so whenever I deploy all file are getting the transfer in cPanel and whatever is not present in git branch are being  deleted.

So the problem is cPanel is client-side client uploads a certain image which is not present in git branch is deleted when auto deploy is running.

Any solution to skip uploads folder to and to check in auto-deploy?

**Below is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` code:**

```
deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST; mirror -Rnev ./ ./public_html/propertynidhiv2 --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### i Updated -Rnev to -Rnv

e means whatever not present in git i will remove from cpanel
now only thodse file being deleted which i updated